# Upate Release Definition using Azure DevOps REST API fails with old copy

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api, azure-cli2

I'm trying to leverage the DevOps API to update a new release definition.  Ultimately, I will be adding a new environment to the release definition but for now I'm just trying to get the update (PUT) method to work.
I've referenced post [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61326850/how-to-set-release-definition-artifacts-using-azure-devops-rest-api) for information.

The code below gets an existing release definition (id=15), bumps the revision, removes the lastRelease property and then makes a change to the description just to change something.

```
function getreleasedefinitionrequest($definitionid, $org, $project)
{
 $requestpath = "/_apis/release/definitions/" + $definitionid + "?api-version=6.0-preview.4"
 $tokeninfo = az account get-access-token | convertfrom-json
 $token = $tokeninfo.accessToken
 $uribase = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/" + $org + "/" + $project
 $uri = $uribase+$requestpath
 $authheader = "Authorization=Bearer " + $token
 $result = az rest --uri $uri --headers $authheader | convertfrom-json
 return $result
}

function putreleasedefinitionrequest($bodyfile, $org, $project)
{
 $requestpath = "/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=6.0-preview.4"
 $tokeninfo = az account get-access-token | convertfrom-json
 $token = $tokeninfo.accessToken
 $uribase = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/" + $org + "/" + $project
 $uri = $uribase+$requestpath
 $authheader = "Authorization=Bearer " + $token
 $result = az rest --method put --uri $uri --headers "Content-Type=application/json" $authheader --body @$bodyfile | convertfrom-json
 return $result
}

$definition15 = getreleasedefinitionrequest "15" {org} {project} | select -Last 1

#bump the revision and delete the lastRelease property
$rev = [int] $definition15.revision
$rev++
$definition15.revision = $rev
$definition15.PSObject.properties.remove('lastRelease')
$definition15.description = "make up a change to the description"

$bodyfile = ".\body.json"

$body = $definition15 | convertto-json -Depth 100 | Set-Content -Path $bodyfile

#upate release definition
$putresult = putreleasedefinitionrequest $bodyfile {org} {project} | select -Last 1
```

The az rest --method put throws an error code complaining that the release is an old copy. I pulled the request from the same version of the API and made changes as describe above. So I'm thinking this new revision is a fresh, new version of the pipeline.

> az : Bad Request({"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"You are
> using an old copy of the release pipeline. Refresh your copy and try
> again.","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement.Data.Exceptions.InvalidRequestException,
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement2.Data","typeKey":"InvalidRequestException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000})

Are there other changes that are required to successfully make the update?

Comment: Can u debug it and paste  definition15 var before and after changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `$rev++`, we **don't and we shouldn't** change the value of `revision` manually.

**Note:** If you read the post carefully, you would see `I set the revision number to be the number it is currently on and it works now`. So we actually doesn't need to change it, the error `You are using an old copy of the release pipeline` always results from the change of `revision`.